# How to take input of a mentioned channel and send message in that channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have the following code to generate embed from a message , it works fine now what I want is after creating embed the bot should ask the user to mention a channel and after the user mentions a channel , the bot should send that embed there. How do I do it?

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Enter title for embed:")
    e = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
    await ctx.send("Enter the content for embed:")
    c = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = e,
        description = c,
        color = 0x03f8fc,
        timestamp= ctx.message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `Client.wait_for()` coroutine to wait for a message from the user. Then I formatted the `message.content` string to get just the ID of the channel. Then I used the discord.utils.get method to get the channel using just the ID.

```py
# at the top of the file
from discord.utils import get


    @client.command()
    async def embed(ctx):

        # embed stuff here
        
        def check(msg):
            # make sure the author of the message we're waiting for is the same user that invoked the command
            return ctx.author == msg.author
        
        await ctx.send("mention a channel to send to")
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        

        msg = msg.content.split("#")[1].split('>')[0]
"""
over here we are spliting the '#' from the message content first and index just the ID with the '>' 
(if the message is just a channel mention it shoud be something like this:  <#000000000000000000>) 
then we split the '>' from the string and index just the ID part and now we have the ID of the channel
"""
        channel = get(ctx.guild.channels, id=int(msg))

        await channel.send(f'{words}')
```

Comment: It doesn't work , If a user sends in format <#00000000000> , discord automatically detects it and mentions the concerned channel , also I want something where user just have to mention the channel like #abc and bot would send the embed there. @blu

Comment: The user doesnt have to send in the format <#00000000000>. The bot sees a mention in that format when the user does #abc. [see example here](https://img.blutopia.ca/w5wj0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using wait_for() and [`TextChannelConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.TextChannelConverter)

```py
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    await ctx.send("Enter title for embed:")
    e = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
    await ctx.send("Enter the content for embed:")
    c = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = e,
        description = c,
        color = 0x03f8fc,
        timestamp= ctx.message.created_at
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = ctx.guild.icon_url)
    channel = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    channel = await commands.TextChannelConverter().convert(ctx, channel.content)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```